# EclipseLink/TopLink full outer join instead left join

Tags: eclipselink, jpql, toplink

On model Card can have or not CardHolder ( 1:1 ), and I would like getting every cards filter by issuer linked to actived cardHolders plus cards without cardHolders, so I need a full outer join. Although the query below translate to left join returning just cards with cardHolders

```
    final ExpressionBuilder builder = new ExpressionBuilder( Card.class );

    Expression queryExp = builder.get( "cardIssuer" ).equal( cardIssuer );
    queryExp = queryExp.and( builder.get( "cardStatus" ).get( "statusType" ).equal( "ACTIVATED" ) );
    queryExp = queryExp.and( builder.getAllowingNull( "cardHolder" )isNull().or(
                  builder.get( "cardHolder" ).get( "status" ).get( "status" ).equal( "ACTIVE" ) ) );


    Expression orderExpression = builder.get( "cardHolder" ).get( "surname" ).descending();


    return getMultiple( queryExp, pageable , Card.class, orderExpression );
```

Translate query is

```
  SELECT COUNT(t0.CARD_ID) FROM CARD t0 LEFT JOIN CARD_HOLDER t3 
 ON (t3.CARD_HOLDER_ID = t0.CARD_HOLDER_ID), CARD_HOLDER_STATUS t2, CARD_STATUS t1 
 WHERE (((((t0.CARD_ISSUER_ID = 10006) AND (t1.STATUS_TYPE = 'ACTIVATED')) AND (t2.STATUS = 'ACTIVE')) 
 AND (t0.CARD_ID IN ('52683','52692'))) 
 AND ((t1.CARD_STATUS_ID = t0.CARD_STATUS_ID) AND (t2.STATUS_ID = t3.STATUS_ID)))
```

Comment: and what is "ExpressionBuilder" ? If it is some EclipseLink API class then kindly remove the JPA tag

Comment: you're right about tag

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/expressions002.htm#CJAJIHBJ

Comment: thanks @Chris, I tried with OR function although I still retrieve rows with cardHolder not null. Query looks like is translated to inner join instead outter

Comment: You are using an inner join (get) as well as an outerjoin (getAllowingNull) on the same relationship. The inner join is more restrictive and always wins. Try reusing your join expression for the other joins rather than calling get( "cardHolder" ) repeatedly

Comment: The issue is because I'm using an old JPA version, unfortunately I can't change it, although I'll post a way using native queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to JPA version the outer join is not properly done, so I found a way through native queries

```java
@NamedNativeQueries( {
@NamedNativeQuery( name = Card.USER_DIRECTORY_BASE,
    query = "select * from card c full outer join card_holder ch on c.card_holder_id = ch.card_holder_id "
      + "where c.CARD_ISSUER_ID = ?1 and c.card_status_id = 1 and ( ch.STATUS_ID = 1 or c.CARD_HOLDER_ID is null) "
      + "order by ch.FORENAME asc", 
    resultClass  = Card.class ),

@NamedNativeQuery( name = Card.USER_DIRECTORY_BASE_COUNT,
    query = "select count(*) from card c full outer join card_holder ch on c.card_holder_id = ch.card_holder_id "
      + "where c.CARD_ISSUER_ID = ?1 and c.card_status_id = 1 and ( ch.STATUS_ID = 1 or c.CARD_HOLDER_ID is null) "
      + "order by ch.FORENAME asc" )
} )
```

And getting results

```java
Query query = em.createNamedQuery( Card.USER_DIRECTORY_BASE);
query.setParamenter(1,10000);
query.getResultList();
```